# Basic Determine exact amount of iterations

Tags: time-complexity, iteration

How exactly do you track the exact amount of iterations? I know its probably basic but can't figure out how so was hoping someone could explain to a complete beginner how you arrive at an answer.

```
def f(n):

i = 4

 while i < n:

 print(i)

 i = i + 1
```

( The answer should be max(n−4,0)  )

Comment: It's not basic at all. There's no general rule to count the exact number of iterations. However, for many common programs you can mentally count them. Above we start counting from $4$ until $n$ is met, hence $n-4$. If that would be negative, instead ...

Comment: Try adding some print statements inside all this and just observe the results.